# Use postmessage in a console application

Tags: multithreading, lazarus, postmessage

I am creating an console application on a raspberry pi in lazarus. This console applications spawns a thread that reads a sensor. I am looking for a way to pass data in a thread safe way from the thread to the main application.

Currently I am using postmessage to send data from the thread to the main application. I have tested this with a GUI and that works fine. When I tried to implement this to an console application I came to the conclusion that an handle is connected to a window.

So the question is: How can I pass data asynchronously from a thread. Can I use postmessage and  create an handle for the console application or is there a different thread safe way to pass on data.

Comment: What OS are you running on the pi

Comment: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie).

Comment: PostMessage is a Windows API function. You can't use it on Linux and you can't be using it in your GUI app unless that runs on Windows only.

Comment: I got it working on Linux with a GUI. What are the alternatives?

Comment: This is clearly some Lazarus compatibility layer that over whichever widget set is being used. You should first study what `PostMessage` is on Lazarus on non Windows platforms.

Comment: Ok, so what I understand is that PostMessage is copied from windows to linux. But I can't find a lot of information on alternatives, most pages direct to post and sendmessage. What would be the linux alternative?

Comment: Try TThread.Queue